# How to iterate through a json values and compare all the json values and returns if true?

Tags: python, json, for-loop, if-statement, key-value

my Jenkins response is like this below:
I want to iterate through all the values in the data and do the comparison like this

```
data = {"fruits":["apple","banana","spinach","carrot"]}

for value in data.json().values():
    if value[i] == apple or banana:
        print value[i] # i want to print if its find one or two
    elif value[i] == spinach or carrot:
        print value[i] # i want to print if it is true
```

The code what i write is wrong but please help me out how to iterate through values and do the comparison and print the values if it exists am new to python

Comment: Where do you define i? Also you should fix your indentation here as white space is part of the code after all

Comment: alright guys it worked Thanks everyone @GreenCell

Comment: Start with an intro to loops in Python maybe? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6iF8Xb7Z3wQ&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @GreenCell can I use os.getenv in if statement for comparing like this              
  if value == apple.banana12.(os.getenv).cdf  or value == banana.56.(os.getenv).lkg                                                
        print value?                                                                                    
 os.getenv is getting the data from Jenkins parameter so I want to insert the data inside the string to compare with the value? how can I do it in python?

Comment: As long as your environment variable with `os.getenv` evaluates to what you want then you can use anything. You might need to ask a new question or edit this question to clarify as it's getting off-topic and not very clear.

Comment: sorry @GreenCell last clarification if  value == apple45.(os.getenv).banana print value can I do like this? can you please tell me what is the correct format to use os.getenv inside a string comparison in if statement?

Comment: `os.getenv` is not used like that. Please ask a new question :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what can fix it:

- Make sure your data is a string
- using `json.loads`
- You don't need the index if you are iterating over the elements of

  ```
  import json
  data = json.loads('{"fruits":["apple","banana","spinach","carrot"]}')
  for value in data['fruits']:
      if value == 'apple' or 'banana':
          print(value) # i want to print if its find one or two
      elif value == 'spinach' or 'carrot':
          print(value) # i want to print if it is true
  ```